# Resistor Heating up in AND gate

Tags: transistors, resistors, logic-gates

I am wiring up an AND gate with 2 2n2222 transistors, a LED and 3 10 Ohm resistors. When I make the AND gate, the LED lights up but there is a weird smell coming from the resistor wired to ground. When I touch the resistor, I find that it is hot! The circuit is wired up correctly and I am giving the right voltage. The only thing is that I am using 10 Ohm resistors instead of a 1 Ohm resistor.

Comment: What voltage..?

Comment: Measure current from Ohm's law and compute V^2/R power dissipation! ok? probably 30 Ohms should be 220 Ohms. You must know Ohm's  Law.

Comment: Show a schematic.

Comment: If the schematic you're working from shows 1Ω resistors, it's probably wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following circuit will work, and in order to determine the value of R3 you'll need to know the supply voltage, \$(V_{CC})\$ the collector-to-emitter saturation voltage \$(V_{CE(SAT)})\$ of the two transistors, and the forward voltage drop of the LED \$(V_F)\$ with the desired current \$(I_F)\$through it.

assuming the transistors drop about 200 millivolts each and the LED drops 2 volts with 20 milliamperes through it, we can say:

$$ R3 =\frac {V_{CC} -(V_{CE(SAT)Q1\ +} V_{CE(SAT)Q2\ +}V_{F(LED)})}   {I_{F(LED)}}$$

$$= \frac{5V -(0.2V+0.2V +2V)}{0.02A}$$

$$=130\text{ ohms,}$$ and the 150 ohm one you have on hand will work just fine.

In order to select the base resistors it's customary, in switching applications, to run about 10% of the value of the collector current into the base, so in this case that would be about 2 milliamperes.

Then assuming about a 0.7 volt drop across Q2's base-to-emitter junction means that you need a resistor between the supply and the base which will drop 4.4 volts with 2 milliamperes through it, and from Ohm's law we have
\$R2=\frac{E}{I} = \frac{4.3V}{0.002A} \approx 2200\text{ ohms}\$

For Q1 it's the same procedure but you have to add Q2's Vce(sat) to Q1's Vbe(sat), so that comes out to \$R1 =\frac{E}{I} = \frac{4V}{0.002A} = 2000\text{ ohms}\$

2000 ohms will work fine in both cases, so your AND looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You didn't say what your "right voltage" is and you didn't give a schematic. There's a schematic editor included on top of the editor box. Use it!

10Ω is a very low resistor value for limiting an LED current (that's what I think you are trying to do), you may burn a few watts on that resistor. Most likely, it's too small. Or your resistance is calculated wrong.

Comment: I didn't put this because I'm new to electronics and I think this is a small difference but I used 5v when the schematic used 6v because my arduino could supply and the link to the schematic is http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/Hbase/Electronic/trangate.html

Comment: this is also the schematic but I got confused from this one because there are no resistor values. But I already ordered some 1 ohm resistors because there was a page that I don't know the link of which said to use 1 ohm resistor.

Comment: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/629800329109714609/

Comment: the 10 ohm resistors are these: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00B5JV8JM/ref=biss_dp_t_asn

Comment: Do a simple power calculation: P=U²/R, meaning P=(5V)²/10Ω == 2.5W. The resistors you use have 0.25W. So you need at least 100Ω. I suggest to buy a good load of 220Ω 0.25W resistors, they are okay for experimenting with 5V.

Comment: So should I replace the 1 ohm I'm ordering with 220?

Comment: Yes. I think the page you don't remember said 1kΩ. That's 1000Ω. Also okay for 5V tinkering but gives you a very small current that isn't lighting up standard LEDs, should you want that.

Comment: Because I didn't have 220 ohm but I have 150 ohm I decided to try that and it worked and didn't heat up or give any smells.

Comment: [^.^] So do your math next time.

Comment: On thing, would wiring resistors together make them have a higher wattage or would it still be 0.25W?

Comment: When you put them in parallel, they can dissipate 0.25W **each**. BUT your resistance drops **also** (10Ω||10Ω==5Ω), making the circuit burn twice the power, so you aren't done yet. You had to use four 10Ω/0.25W resistors wired in series and parallel to get one 10Ω/1W resistor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47338/discussion-between-david-and-janka).

Answer (score 0):

For a reasonably acceptable AND gate, try the following circuit. You'll need one more of your NPN BJTs. But it will work reasonably well. No over-heating.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYFKI0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this circuit, a "1" happens when the switch is open. A "0" happens when the switch is closed. Both switches must be open for the LED to light up.

Comment: 150 ohm resistor is working as a substitute for 220 ohms recommended.